# Gradle unable to find downloaded dependency packaged as OSGi bundle (non-OSGi app)

Tags: java, jar, osgi, jersey, gradle

**(Edited for clarification)**

My (non-OSGi) application build is in Gradle, and I am trying to upgrade from very old version of Jersey (1.1.4.1) to something much newer (1.12?).  I do not pretend to know anything about using OSGi.  But when I point my Gradle dependencies (with `$JERSEY_VERSION` set to "1.12") to:

`[group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-server', version: "$JERSEY_VERSION"]`

it downloads the jersey-server-1.12.jar into my Gradle dependencies cache under a "bundles" directory instead of the normal "jars" directory, and then Gradle seems to not include this jar in its classpath like it would if it were under a "jars" subdirectory instead.

I discovered it went under "bundles" because the POM has it labeled as an OSGi enabled jar.  I do not think we are going to want to OSGi-ify our project.  Am I stuck with older versions of Jersey, or is there anything else I can do to get Gradle to see the Jersey jar?  I would prefer to *not* manually copy the file to a local repo if possible, but rather somehow depend on the dependency management capabilities of Gradle if it is up to the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Twas a silly oversight: moving from 1.1.4.1 to 1.12, the POM dependencies changed, so that jersey-core.jar was no longer being brought in implicitly.  I had to add jersey-core.jar explicitly.  I had assumed the problem was the fact that jersey-server.jar was being imported as a bundle, but I was really just getting a ClassNotFoundException for a class that was in jersey-core.jar.

Answer (score 0):

OSGi bundles are normal jars with extra manifest entries. You should be able to use them in a non OSGi project as you would any other dependency. Is it a problem that they end up in the cache's bundles directory?

Comment: yes, gradle does not seem to find it there by default.  I don't know whether there was any way to configure gradle to look there as well.  I have been unable to find such advice on the gradle documentation web pages so far.  If I need to I can manually download the jar into a local repository instead, but I'd prefer not to.